# C# Topshelf fails to execute a powershell file

Tags: c#, powershell, service, topshelf

After installing the service (.exe) and starting it, the powershell file in the code will be executed. There are also no error messages.

My Steps:

1. `cd C:\Users\USER_XY\source\repos\ServiceApp\ServiceApp\bin\Debug\net6.0`
2. `.\ScriptAsService.exe install -servicename "MyService123" -displayname "My Service123" -description "This is my service123."`
3. start the service (right click, start)
   [image: rigth click on "MyService123" and then choose "start"]
4. the start.txt and stop.txt will be generated but the powershell script will not be executed.

Here the c# code:

```
using Topshelf;

public class App
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var exitCode = HostFactory.Run(x =>
        {
            x.Service<ScriptAsService>(s =>
            {
                s.ConstructUsing(service => new ScriptAsService());
                s.WhenStarted(service => service.Start());
                s.WhenStopped(service => service.Stop());
            });

            x.RunAsLocalSystem();
        });
    }
}


public class ScriptAsService
{
    private String _scriptfile = @"C:\Users\USER_XY\source\repos\ServiceApp\ServiceApp\bin\Debug\net6.0\myscript.ps1";

    public void Start()
    {
        File.WriteAllText("start.txt", "service started --> start scriptfile=" + _scriptfile);

        ProcessStartInfo process_start_info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        process_start_info.FileName = "powershell.exe";
        process_start_info.Arguments = this._scriptfile;
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = process_start_info;
        process.Start();

        process.WaitForExit();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        File.WriteAllText("stop.txt", "service stopped");
    }
}
```

And here the powershell code (myscript.ps1):

```
$counter = 0
while (1)
{
  Add-Content info22.txt -Value "content = $counter"
  $counter++
  Start-Sleep -s 15
}
```

I except the info22.txt file. This file will be created by the powershell script.

Comment: How would you know that there are no error messages? You never read any output from the `powershell.exe` process, let alone check it's exit code...

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen
Iif the service would throw an error then the service would be terminated. But the service is not terminated.

Comment: I'm not talking about the service process, I'm talking about the `powershell.exe` _child process_ that your service process launches when `Start()` is called :)

Comment: Was service started with an account?  Services by default are started as System with no account and there is no environment.  So powershell.exe will not be found.  Try starting the service with "Run As"